# Python: Create multiple lists with increasing size

Tags: python, random, list-comprehension

How would you create multiple lists populated with random numbers on bigger from previous preferably using list comprehension.

Example:

create 3 lists

```
list_1=[47]
list_2=[56,76]
list_3=[754,45,43]
```

Comment: It's not clear what you're looking for. What was "on bigger from previous" intended to mean? How should these random numbers be distributed?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
 import random
 [[random.randint(1, 1000) for _ in range(list_size)] for list_size in range(1,4)]
```

Comment: Great was looking exactly for this.